# How to use python path as object

Tags: python, path, flask

I'm trying to use the path as an argument in a function but it doesn't work. I don't know how to proceed..

```
foo=['a','b','c']

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def switch(path)
 return path[0]
```

When I go to /foo, I would like to have 'a' but it doesn't work..

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like this

```
path_map={'foo':'a','bar':'b','baz':'c'}

@app.route('/<path>')
def switch(path)
    return path_map[path]
```

/foo returns a

/bar returns b

/baz returns c

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

foo = ['a','b','c']

@app.route('/<path:path>')
def switch(path):
    return path[0]                                                              

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Does your code look like this? After running this script, you can get the result at **yoursite/a:a**